# After creating new instance in collection, don't do a GET request on the endpoint (backbone)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

After I add a model instance to a collection, I do a POST request to add it. Then a GET request is done to get the model from the server. Is there a way to not to the GET request, only the POST request? Also, is it possible to get the success and error callback functions to respond to the success and failure of the POST request?

I want to do this because the collection has a URL that parses the JSON data that gets back, so the GET request doesn't work, but the POST request does work. I don't want to do a GET request on a endpoint that doesn't work.

Comment: I think it would really help if you could be much more specific as to what your problem is and what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GET request is unnecessary. On the server in your POST handler you should return a JSON result back to the client representing the model. This is especially useful when there are generated fields such as an id. Then on the client in the success callback you can grab the model returned from the POST.

In the following example a new model is added to the collection if successful. I've also included the error callback which will fire if either client side validation fails or the POST fails:

```
var isNew = this.model.isNew();
this.model.save({}, {
    success: function(model, response) {
        if (isNew && this.collection) {
            this.collection.add(model);
        }   
    },
    error: function(model, response) {
        var errorMsg;
        // Response may be string (if failed client side validation or an AJAX response (if failed server side)
        if (_.isString(response))
            errorMsg = response;
        else
            errorMsg = response.responseText;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The process you follow is indeed unnecessary. You should be using `create` on the collection to directly add the model, and invoke `sync` (the POST in this case) in the same time.

For example:

`collection.create({foo: 'bar'});` or `collection.create(unsaved_model);`

The result of invoking `create` will return either the (saved) model or `false` if this was not successful. In addition it is possible to wait for the model to be saved `before` adding to the collection by doing

```
collection.create({foo: 'bar'}, {wait: true});
```

The [documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-create) is your friend.